# SQL Server calculated column's metadata

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

Suppose that we have table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tab(id INT PRIMARY KEY
                     -- other columns
                     ,is_active BIT);

INSERT INTO dbo.tab(id, is_active)
VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3,0);
```

The case is to add calculated column that will change `NULL` to `0` and return original values when possible.

Final result:

- original columns have to stay untouched (so there is no possibility to `UPDATE` and `ALTER` table)
- calculated column has to have correct type and nullability
- cannot use `VIEW/TRIGGER/...`

So let's just add that column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tab(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ,is_active BIT
  ,calc_flag1 AS CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active) AS BIT)

  ,calc_flag2 AS CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,ISNULL(is_active,0)) AS BIT)
  ,calc_flag3 AS IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 , ISNULL(is_active,0))

  ,calc_flag4 AS CAST(ISNULL(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 , is_active), 0) AS BIT)
  ,calc_flag5 AS ISNULL(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active),0)

  ,calc_flag6 AS ISNULL(CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active) AS BIT),
                      CAST(0 AS BIT))
);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/SSE99539)**</kbd>

Data:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tab;

╔══╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║id║is_active║calc_flag1║calc_flag2║calc_flag3║calc_flag4║calc_flag5║calc_flag6║
╠══╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1║ NULL    ║ False    ║ False    ║        0 ║ False    ║        0 ║ False    ║
║ 2║ True    ║ True     ║ True     ║        1 ║ True     ║        1 ║ True     ║
║ 3║ False   ║ False    ║ False    ║        0 ║ False    ║        0 ║ False    ║
╚══╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

And metadata check:

```
EXEC sp_help 'dbo.tab';

╔═════════════╦══════╦══════════╦════════╦══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Column_name ║ Type ║ Computed ║ Length ║ Prec ║ Scale ║ Nullable ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬════════╬══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ id          ║ int  ║ no       ║      4 ║  10  ║     0 ║ no       ║
║ is_active   ║ bit  ║ no       ║      1 ║      ║       ║ yes      ║
║ calc_flag1  ║ bit  ║ yes      ║      1 ║      ║       ║ yes      ║
║ calc_flag2  ║ bit  ║ yes      ║      1 ║      ║       ║ yes      ║
║ calc_flag3  ║ int  ║ yes      ║      4 ║   10 ║     0 ║ no       ║
║ calc_flag4  ║ bit  ║ yes      ║      1 ║      ║       ║ yes      ║
║ calc_flag5  ║ int  ║ yes      ║      4 ║   10 ║     0 ║ no       ║
║ calc_flag6  ║ bit  ║ yes      ║      1 ║      ║       ║ no       ║
╚═════════════╩══════╩══════════╩════════╩══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

**First attempt:**

```
,calc_flag1 AS CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active) AS BIT)
```

Correct datatype but it cannot get nullability. I can understand that because it has hardcoded value and column that is nullable so the entire expression is evaluated as nullable.

**Second attempt:**

```
,calc_flag2 AS CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,ISNULL(is_active,0)) AS BIT)
```

Same as before but with explicit `ISNULL(is_active, 0)`. Now it should work because there is hardcoded value and `ISNULL` but it doesn't.

```
,calc_flag3 AS IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 , ISNULL(is_active,0))
```

That is interesting, without `CAST` it get `nullable` - `no`, but datatype is `INT` now.

**Third attempt**:

```
,calc_flag4 AS CAST(ISNULL(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 , is_active), 0) AS BIT)
```

Casting `ISNULL` when the second value is hardcoded. **Why this can be `nullable`?**

```
,calc_flag5 AS ISNULL(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active),0)
```

Of course without casting it works as it should.

**Final attempt**:

```
,calc_flag6 AS ISNULL(CAST(IIF(is_active IS NULL,0 ,is_active) AS BIT),
                      CAST(0 AS BIT))
```

Now I get correct datatype and nullability but it is somehow ugly.

---

The question is why it behaves that way and cannot get correct metadata when `calc_flag2` or `calc_flag4` is used.

Comment: Curious... I have voted to close and migrate to the dba site, where hopefully Paul White or someone with similar expertise on the internals of SQL Server will see it. For what it is worth you can get a non nullable bit column using simply `calc_flag7 AS ISNULL(is_active, 0)`

Comment: I think  the problem can be simplified to why does `ISNULL(is_active,0)` yield a non nullable bit column, yet simply adding a convert like `CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(is_active,0))`, causes the same column to be nullable. Using a specific section from [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114266/7257)(I knew Paul White would have the answer!) the reason is that some setting sessions can cause a conversion overflow to return null, so the only way to ensure a non nullable column is if the outer most function is `ISNULL`.

Comment: Another note is that a `CASE` expression will only have a non nullable return type if **all** the return expressions are not nullable, so even though when you use `IIF(is_active IS NULL,0,is_active)`, the return expression for false will never be reached if it is null, it is still a nullable return type, so the type returned is nullable.

Comment: @GarethD Yes, now it has perfect sense. Thanks for your explanations and link. Will you compile answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that when using `IIF` (which is expanded to a `CASE` expression behind the scenes), the result will only be nullable if **all** the return expressions are not nullable, so when you use:

```
IIF(is_active IS NULL,0,is_active)
```

Although logically when you get to `is_active` in the expression for false it will never be null because of the condition set, this is irrelevant to the compiler, it can just see that one of the returned expressions is `is_active` which is a nullable column, therefore the type returned is nullable.

I think the problem can be simplified to why does ISNULL(is_active,0) yield a non nullable bit column, yet simply adding a convert like CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(is_active,0)), causes the same column to be nullable.

A quick Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ,is_active BIT
  ,calc_flag1 AS ISNULL(is_active, 0)
  ,calc_falg2 AS CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(is_active, 0))
);

EXECUTE tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#tab';
```

Which gives pertinent results of

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Nullable
--------------------------------------------
id          int     no          no
is_active   bit     no          yes
calc_flag1  bit     yes         no
calc_falg2  bit     yes         yes
```

Using a specific section from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114266/7257) (Credit to [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white)) the reason is that some setting sessions can cause a conversion overflow to return null, so the only way to ensure a non nullable column is if the outer most function is `ISNULL`.

The required solution can be achieved simply using `ISNULL(is_active, 0)` as demonstrated above, since this returns a non nullable bit column, but it is worth noting that if a conversion is required, for example, if you needed it to be a int column, then the conversion must be inside the `ISNULL`. Since `ISNULL` will return the type of the first argument, only one conversion is required, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY
  ,is_active BIT
  ,calc_flag1 AS ISNULL(is_active, 0)
  ,calc_falg2 AS CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(is_active, 0))
  ,calc_flag_int AS ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, is_active), 0)
);

EXECUTE tempdb.dbo.sp_help '#tab';
```

Which gives pertinent results of

```
Column_name     Type    Computed    Nullable
--------------------------------------------
id              int     no          no
is_active       bit     no          yes
calc_flag1      bit     yes         no
calc_falg2      bit     yes         yes
calc_falg_int   int     yes         no
```

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, ...

> Unless otherwise specified, computed columns are virtual columns that are not physically stored in the table. Their values are recalculated every time they are referenced in a query.
>
> The Database Engine automatically determines the nullability of computed columns based on the expressions used. The result of most expressions is considered nullable even if only nonnullable columns are present, because possible underflows or overflows will produce null results as well. Use the COLUMNPROPERTY function with the AllowsNull property to investigate the nullability of any computed column in a table. **An expression that is nullable can be turned into a nonnullable one by specifying ISNULL(check_expression, constant), where the constant is a nonnull value substituted for any null result.**

So I would say that since your is_active field is nullable, the engine computes that it is still possible to get to a null condition until you specifically guard against them in the final ISNULL.

I am going to try and create an overflow or underflow that results in a null for the bit column upon insert in order to validate the engine but your question does seem valid in that the expression you have in the calculated column specifically guards using the case statement.